# Registro con Google en Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, login

Estoy realizando un login con el SDK de firebase para que se pueda iniciar sesión con Google, al momento de registrar al usuario recupero su email y displayName, mi pregunta es si se puede recuperar la fecha de nacimiento o el genero de igual manera que se recupera el email o el displayName.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: No es posible directamente debes solicitar la data al proveedor mediante--->https://androiderrors.com/firebase-auth-get-additional-user-info-age-gender/